# How to save Python dictionary to csv file without index?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I stored 3 `DataFrame` in a dictionary called `dict`, and I would like to save all the dataframes in a csv file like this,

```
      dict 
      Key  Type        Size    Value
      001  DataFrame   (3,4)   Columns names: date, count, number, expiration
      002  DateFrame   (3,4)   Columns names: date, count, number, expiration               
      003  DateFrame   (3,4)   Columns names: date, count, number, expiration

      Index      date     count  number    expiration
       0      1991-10-01    3     001      1992-10-01
       1      1991-10-02    5     002      1992-10-02
       2      1991-10-03    7     003      1992-10-03
```

I tried,

```
with open('data.csv','w') as f:
     w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = '\t')
     w.writerows(dict.items())
```

But it turns out like this, one row with all the values and also Index[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can youse `to_csv` function of class `DataFrame`:

```
df.to_csv('/path/to/file.csv',sep='\t')
```

(assuming your `DataFrame` is named `df`)

---

UPDATE: if you have multiple DataFrames of the same type then you can merge them in one DataFrame (instead of keeping them in a dictionary separately) and use `to_csv` function to store it.

Comment: The `DataFrame` are stored in a dictionary.

Comment: Why don't you use the `to_csv` function? you can merge the three DataFrames that you have and then use `to_csv`

Comment: Since I have around 200+ dataframes, I think it would be better to store them in a dictionary. Or do you think there's a better way to solve the problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: First of all, what do you mean by storing in a dictionary? second, what is the size of each DataFrame and why don't you merge them if they are containing the same types of data?

Comment: The dictionary contains multiple dataframes. All dataframes have columns 'date', 'count', 'number', 'expiration' and the same size (3rows, 4columns). Yes, I used `pd.concat` to merge them and it worked pretty well. I finally save them in a CSV file. Thank you.